# WebAPI cannot find WCF endpoint element

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, endpoint

I am attempting to consume a working C# WCF service (RCWindsSvc) via a .Net 4.5 C# MVC4 WebAPI (RCWindsExtSvc).  I am receiving the following runtime error when calling the WCF service from the WebAPI:

*'Could not find endpoint element with name 'RCWindsSvcEndpoint' and contract RCWindsSvc.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.'*

The system.serviceModel from the web.config in the WCF Service is:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="RCWindsSvc.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="RCWindsSvc.Service1Behavior">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:15021/RCWinds.svc"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="RCWindsSvc.IService1"
          behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          name="RCWindsSvcEndpoint"/>
      <!-- behaviorConfiguration="WebBehaviour" /> -->
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="RCWindsSvc.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <!-- <behavior name="webBehaviour">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>-->
      <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am using ConfigurationChannelFactory in the WebAPI code to retrieve the WCF configuration data, and the following is the code from the WebAPI Controller:

```
public String[] GetStationNames()
        {
            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "web.config";
            Configuration newConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            ConfigurationChannelFactory<RCWindsSvc.IService1> factory1 = new
                ConfigurationChannelFactory<RCWindsSvc.IService1>("RCWindsSvcEndpoint", newConfiguration, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:15021/RcWinds.svc"));
            RCWindsSvc.IService1 client1 = factory1.CreateChannel();

            IEnumerable<string> stationNames = client1.GetStationNames();
            return stationNames.ToArray();

        }
```

This seems to be a somwhat common issue and I have explored a number of suggested solutions to no avail.  Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, can you display wsdl when you browse to http://localhost:15021/RCWinds.svc?wsdl ?

Comment: Thiago - yes, the wsdl displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a client section in your configuration file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            ...
        </bindings>
        <client>
           <endpoint address="http://localhost:15021/RCWinds.svc"
               binding="webHttpBinding" 
               contract="RCWindsSvc.IService1" name="RCWindsSvcEndpoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thiago, I added the client section to the WCF configuration file but I am still receiving the error.

Comment: Did you add in both .config files (wcf / webapi) ?

Comment: No, just the WCF service. I was under the impression that the ConfigurationChannelFactory would make the new WCF configuration available to the WebAPI.

Comment: Why can't you call wcf service just using WebRequest.Create through your webapi?

Comment: I am not familiar with that process - is that the recommended direction?

Comment: since you're exposing your wcf with http binding, you'll consume it using http. WebRequest.Create under System.Net will help you with that.

Comment: The RCWindsExtSvc WebAPI is meant to reside on an external web server sitting outside the firewall and available to the public.  RCWindsExtSvc would the consume the internal RCWindsSvc which performs all the interaction with the data.

Comment: Ok, but as I said, the communication between Webapi / wcf will be http. There's no need to channel factory. Take a look: http://quicktejarat.com/ShiftNibble/post/2013/02/14/Problem-in-Consuming-WCF-Service-from-Aspnet-WebApi.aspx

Comment: Thank you - I will review your suggested approach.